# Java driver - BSON filter check if record is deleted?

Tags: mongodb-java, spring-mongodb

I am trying to get valid records from mongodb using Spring - mongodb - java driver
my question is around the creation of the Bson filter

I am looking for matching records that match some filter (printer_Type and manufacture_Id )
and the records aren't deleted (isDeleted=true)
my issue is that isDeleted can exist or not on the record.
so including that exists clause made me confused.

I wasn't able to do it in mongo without java
https://mongoplayground.net/p/U0N6FJLUWTk

```
Bson filter = and(
                and(
                   eq("printer_Type",ConfigurationTypes.PRINTER_TYPES)
                   ,
                   eq("manufacture_Id",manufactureId)
                ,
               or(
                       exists("isDeleted"),
                       eq("isDeleted",Boolean.FALSE)
                  ))
                );
```

so for example for this list

```
    [
{"manufacture_Id":"XEROX",  "printer_Type":"officeJet", "printerTypeName":"Office Jet", isDeleted:true },
{"manufacture_Id":"XEROX",  "printer_Type":"homeJet","printerTypeName":"Home Jet",     },
{"manufacture_Id":"HP",      "printer_Type":"homeJet","printerTypeName":"Home Jet",     },
{"manufacture_Id":"XEROX",  "printer_Type":"homeJet1","printerTypeName":"Home Jet 1",   isDeleted:false  },
{"manufacture_Id":"XEROX",  "printer_Type":"homeJet2","printerTypeName":"Home Jet 2",   isDeleted:true   },
{"manufacture_Id":"XEROX",  "printer_Type":"homeJet3","printerTypeName":"Home Jet 3",   isDeleted:true   },
{"manufacture_Id":"XEROX",  "printer_Type":"homeJet4","printerTypeName":"Home Jet 4"   }
]
```

So for manufacure id XEROX  (and any printer type) I should get back:

```
Home jet
Home Jet 1
Home Jet 4
```

full code:

```
    Bson projectionFields = Projections.fields(
            Projections.include("printerTypeName"),
            Projections.excludeId());
    
    Bson filter = and(
                    and(
                       eq("printer_Type",ConfigurationTypes.PRINTER_TYPES)
                       ,
                       eq("manufacture_Id",manufactureId)
                    ,
                   or(
                           exists("isDeleted"),
                           eq("isDeleted",Boolean.FALSE)
                      ))
                    );
    
    Document doc = collection.find(filter)
            .projection(projectionFields)
            .sort(Sorts.descending("printerType"))
            .first();
            
    if (doc == null) {
        System.out.println("No results found for printer Type Name");
        return null;
    } else {
        System.out.println(doc.toJson());
        return doc.getString("printerTypeName");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So for manufacure id XEROX (and any printer type) I should get back:
>
> Home jet Home Jet 1 Home Jet 4

For any **printer_Type** the required query would look like this

```
db.collection.find({
  "manufacture_Id": "XEROX",
  "isDeleted": {
    $ne: true
  }
})
```

- The first filter matches documents with "**manufacture_Id**" equal to
  "XEROX".
- The second filter matches documents that have "**isDeleted**"    field
  either not present or not equal to true.

You can try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YuXTBuPG2Nk)

Bson filter what are you looking for based on your code snippet:

```
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;

Bson filter = Filters.and(Filters.eq("manufacture_Id", manufactureId), Filters.eq("printer_Type", ConfigurationTypes.PRINTER_TYPES), Filters.ne("isDeleted", true));
```

...